# This.color in css?

Tags: css, sass, less

Or maybe there's preprocessor solution.

Suppose you have 20 `buttons`. Each with a different color.

The colors are set like this:

```
button {
  background: red;
}
```

So you can write something like this

```
button:hover {
  this.background: darken(10%);
}
```

And this will darken each button's background color.

Instead of writing color codes for each button which is `red`, `blue`, `green`, etc... And this can be applied also to more CSS properties.

Without JS of course.

Do they plan to introduce it? Is there a solutin via SASS/LESS/Stylus ?

Comment: You could set `opacity:1` on `:hover` and `opacity:0.9` otherwise, which would have a somewhat similar effect.

Comment: @royhowie yea, I was thinking bout that too :) But its a workaround, I'd like to know whether CSS/Preprocessor means offer something of the kind.

Comment: How are the colors set?

Comment: I don't think there's any way to do that.

Comment: Sass has [color functions](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html) pretty sure all the other preprocessors do as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing like that in Sass, but you can use a mixin like this code:

```
@mixin addColor($color) {
  background: $color;

  &:hover {
    background: darken($color, 10%);
  } 
}

.foo {
  @include addColor(red);
}

.anotherFoo {
  @include addColor(blue);
}
```